# OpenCV Mat_ template constructor undefined reference

Tags: opencv

I can't get the cv::Mat_ constructor to compile that makes a view over user-allocated data. Here's a toy example that'll crash upon execution, but suffices for demonstrating compilation errors.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace cv;

void f(){
    int size_[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int dimension_ = 3;
    float* data = nullptr;
    size_t bytes = 0;
    Mat_<float> image_mat(dimension_, size_, data, &bytes);
}
```

Compiling above code with

```
nick@hawaii:~/opencv-undefined-ref$ clang++ main.cpp -std=c++11  -l opencv_core
```

Gives me

```
/tmp/main-15f5e8.o: In function `f()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `cv::Mat_<float>::Mat_(int, int const*, float*, unsigned long const*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looking through `opencv2/core/mat.hpp`, I also can't find the template-definition for this constructor... is it forgotten? Or am I missing something? Should I include another header?

This is on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, opencv-core-dev Version: 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1

Comment: I have the same error, and the specific constructor is not in mat.hpp. That make sense since `Mat_<float>` is a 1 channel matrix of float, not a N-dims matrix. Do you simply want to create a 3 channel float matrix?

Comment: I want an N-dimensional array of float, single channel. There's a decl for it, there should've been a definition somewhere.

Comment: You can use `Mat image_mat(dimension_, size_, CV_32F, data, &bytes)`, or `Mat1f image_mat(Mat(dimension_, size_, CV_32F, data, &bytes));`. `Mat1f` is just a typedef for `Mat_<float>`

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using at the moment. Feel free to answer this as workaround (but do note in the answer there doesn't seem to be a definition for the provided decl).

Comment: Thanks, feel free to post your own answer